# Datastage: Split string by every tenth delimiter

Tags: datastage

I have a parameter which is long string delimited by comma(~1500 values). Like 1,2,3,4,5,etc .
This parameter transmitted in parallel job for processing, 1 value at a time. I need to transmitted not 1 value, but 10 at once.
I tried with the help of the stage UserVariables to change every tenth comma to another delimiter. but I have not succeeded so far

If anyone knows how I can do this, please tell me

Big thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Field() function using 10 as the value of its fourth argument.  You'll need to advance the third argument also, so will probably need a loop with two User Variables activities.
`Field(string, delimiter, start, #fields)`
So:
Field(paramList, ",", 1, 10)
Field(paramList, ",", 11, 10)
Field(paramList, ",", 21, 10)
and so on.